# Xcode Compiler Error - Changing the "Optimize for Speed" Setting Causes my App to Crash

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoa

***tldr:*** Changing the "Optimize for Speed" Swift Compiler setting from "`No Optimization [-Onone]`" to "`Optimize for Speed [-O]`" causes a string typecast to fail

### Background

I am using a function from [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49076860/5424873) in a program that I am making. It finds the url of an open TextEdit document

### Problem

When I try to run my program with optimization turned on it crashes on this line

```
let filePath = result as! String
```

I am trying to find out how to get the `String` from the `result` variable.

The strange thing is that I can print the `result` variable to the console even if `Optimize for Speed [-O]` is on

### How to reproduce

1. Download the project [here](https://github.com/jonpdw/Optimize-for-Speed-String-Cast-Problem)
2. Ensure the app is not sandboxed
3. Give the app accessibility permissions
4. Open a TextEdit document and save it to disk
5. Run app

**Image of XCode with the `No Optimization [-Onone]` setting**
[image: With Optimization Off]
**Image of XCode with the `Optimize for Speed [-O]` setting on**
[image: With Optimization ON]

**AppDelegate.swift Code**

```
import Cocoa

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {


    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        getOpenTextEditDocument()
    }

}

func getOpenTextEditDocument() -> URL? {
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49076103/swift-get-file-path-of-currently-opened-document-in-another-application

    if AXIsProcessTrusted() == false {
        print("No Accesability Permissions")
        return nil
    }

    let textEditIdentifier = "com.apple.TextEdit"
    let TextEditApp : NSRunningApplication? = NSRunningApplication
        .runningApplications(withBundleIdentifier: textEditIdentifier).last as NSRunningApplication?

    if let pid = TextEditApp?.processIdentifier {

        var result = [AXUIElement]()
        var windowList: AnyObject? = nil // [AXUIElement]

        let appRef = AXUIElementCreateApplication(pid)

        if AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(appRef, "AXWindows" as CFString, &windowList) == .success {
            result = windowList as! [AXUIElement]
        }

        var docRef: AnyObject? = nil
        guard let result_first = result.first else { return nil }
        if AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(result_first, "AXDocument" as CFString, &docRef) == .success {
            let result = docRef as! AXUIElement

            let filePath = result as! String
            print("filePath = \(result)")
            let filePathURL = URL(string: filePath)
            return filePathURL
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: `result` is an `AXUIElement`, so the statement `result as! String` is just going to forcibly cast an AXUIElement to a String object which is incorrect, hazardous, and unpredictable. If you need the string representation of an `AXUIElement` you'll need to convert it.

Comment: Thanks, I did string(describing) instead and it worked